# How many is too many Laravel model and view count

Tags: php, laravel

I'm somewhat new to laravel and working on my first full-stack laravel project. I've been trying to follow the best practices of laravel to help with better optimization and performance. In the dashboard area of my app, I noticed that the models on some of my pages have 253 counts and the view in my dashboard layout has 17 counts when I check the Laravel debugger stats [see image below].

[image]

In the image above, I have a country model that has 249 rows of all countries in the world (which are used as dropdown select for users to pick their countries), as well as a notification (this count varies per user).

From my knowledge so far, I know data like countries that rarely change can be cached but I'd like to know how many is too many when it comes to `Models` and `Views` count. So I can always watch out for those values, in case I find myself in situations where I can't use cache or before data is cached.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is fine, if you need to display 249 records from the table then you will have to pull 249 records (or models).

What is an issue is when you involve relationships and you come across issues such as the n+1 query prblem; which is described here: [What is the "N+1 selects problem" in ORM (Object-Relational Mapping)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping)